# Calculate document frequency using HashMap [Java]

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to calculate document frequency (i.e. in how many documents each word appears), example:

Doc1: `this phone is the greatest phone ever.`
Doc2: `what's your phone number.`

Result:

```
this              1
phone             2
is                1
the               1
ever              1
what's            1
your              1
number            1
```

I have the following code in Java

```
HashMap<String, String> wordDoc = new HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, Integer> countDfIndex = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

if (!wordDoc.containsKey(word)) {
    wordDoc.put(word,docno);
    countDfIndex.put(word, 1);
}
if (wordDoc.get(word)!=null) {
    if(!wordDoc.containsValue(docno)) {
        wordDoc.put(word,docno);
        countDfIndex.put(word, countDfIndex.get(word)+1);
    }
}
```

I am not getting the right result, Kindly help!!

Comment: what's result do you expect?

Comment: its unclear, are you trying to count the words?

Comment: What's the point of checking ``!wordDoc.containsValue(docno)``?

Comment: I think OP is after number of occurrences in distinct documents - see the word "phone" - occurs three times in two docs, result is 2.

Comment: Yes as Jiri said, Phone appears 3 times totally, but in 2 distinct docs, I'm looking for occurrence in distinct documents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're trying to count number of documents containing the respective word, rather than total number of occurrences.

If so:

```
Map<String, Integer> countDfIndex = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (... document : documents) {
    Set<String> alreadyAdded = new HashSet<String>(); // new empty set for each document

    ...

    if (!alreadyAdded.contains(word)) {
        if (!countDfIndex.containsKey(word) {
            countDfIndex.put(word, 1);
        } else {
            countDfIndex.put(word, countDfIndex.get(word) + 1);
        }
        alreadyAdded.add(word); // don't add the word anymore if found again in the document
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Jiri, I'm looping through word : words instead of document, example if my doc is doc1 , it will loop through all words then will go to another, I tried implement your code but I'm not getting the right frequency, everything is 1

Comment: Do you first loop through documents then through all words in it, or you loop through words in some other way? If the first, reset the `alreadyAdded` at document start then loop through words. If the second is true, how do you know to which document a word belongs?

Comment: Thank you so much, it took a while but i got what you suggested to work, your logic was that kept me going.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void add(Map<String, Integer> map, String word) {
    map.put(word, map.containsKey(word) ? map.get(word) + 1 : 1);
}
```

---

```
for (String i : s.replace(".", "").split(" ")) add(map, i);
```

where,

- `map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();`
- `s = "this phone is the greatest phone ever. what's your phone number."`

Finally, the map contains

```
{the=1, ever=1, number=1, phone=3, this=1, what's=1, is=1, your=1, greatest=1}
```

Comment: The proposed `add` function can be replaced with `map.merge(i, 1, (u,v) -> u+v);`

Comment: Im looking for distinct document count not total count, thanks for helping

Comment: @AndrewTobilko I already had what youve provided, im already using it to calculate the total frequency of words, itll be great if you can teell me how to keep phone to 2, the code is in a loop of words

Answer (score 2):

```
HashMap<String, Integer> countDfIndex = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

if (!countDfIndex.containsKey(word))
    {
      countDfIndex.put(word, 1);
    }
else{
int i =countDfIndex.get(word);
countDfIndex.put(word,i+1);
}
for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> pair: countDfIndex.entrySet()){   

                int count=pair.getValue();
                String word=pair.getKey();
                System.out.println("word is "+word+"count is "+count);

            }
```